# CSS Animation not working properly

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a very simple animation that fades out and shrinks a `div`.

But the problem is that when the animation finishes it goes back to the start and stays there.

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 80px;
}

.fade-out {
    animation-name: fade-out;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes fade-out {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    50% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; height: 0;}
}
```

```html
 
  <div class="fade-out">Style Test</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to your `.fade-out` rule it will fix your animation.

`animation-fill-mode` specifies how CSS rules should be applied before and after executing the animation. The default is `none` which means that before and after the animation is executed, it will not apply any of the animation styles. That's why you're seeing it revert to the pre-animation state.

`forwards` tells the browser to retain the styles from the last keyframe. That's what you're looking for.

See [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) for more information.

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 80px;
}

.fade-out {
    animation-name: fade-out;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fade-out {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    50% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; height: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="fade-out">Style Test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) property

```
.fade-out {
    animation-name: fade-out;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards
}
```